# Finding the First and Third Quartiles

Tags: c#, math

What I want to do is get the middle of each half of my number.
So what I have already created is a way to get the middle of the number (The median in math terms) here;

```
    public static String Find_Median()
    {
        double Size = list.Count;
        double Final_Number = 0;
        if (Size % 2 == 0)
        {
            int HalfWay = list.Count / 2;
            double Value1 = Convert.ToDouble(list[HalfWay - 1].ToString());
            double Value2 = Convert.ToDouble(list[HalfWay - 1 + 1].ToString());
            double Number = Value1 + Value2;
            Final_Number = Number / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            int HalfWay = list.Count / 2;
            double Value1 = Convert.ToDouble(list[HalfWay].ToString());
            Final_Number = Value1;
        }
        return Convert.ToString(Final_Number);
    }
```

That gets the exact middle number of all the numbers in the list, even if its got to middle it does that math also.
I want to do that on both sides; here's an example;

```
3 2 1 4 5 6
```

The middle (median) of that list is 3.5.
I want to use math to find 2, which is between the start and the middle of the equation. also known as Q1 in the IQR. I also want to know how I can find the middle number between the median (middle) and the end, which is 5.

[image]

I.E. So i can find 70,80 and 90 with code.

Comment: What should the answer be for the list `4 3 2 1`?

Comment: `list[list.Count/2]`, `list[list.Count/4]`, `list[3*list.Count/4]`, is that what you want?

Comment: @SWeko Not sure how to get the first and thired from such a small pool of numbers, but in math the numbers lists are always larger then 4.

Comment: Why not just split this list into two more lists and use the same method? `list1 = list.Where(x => x < Final_Number)`, `list2 = list.Where(x => x > Final_Number)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly do that, hence why i am needing some help :3

Comment: @Metab So basically you are unsure of the requirements, and cannot solve them by hand?

Comment: No i can solve them by hand, I am creating a program that will save me useless sorting and basic math, as i have so many of these to do and understand them perfectly i feel making a program will not only help understand but finish them quicker

@E.T. there is no ArrayList.Where function :/

Comment: Why not use List<object> instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the same metod on the following lists:

```
list1 = list.Where(x => x < Median)
list2 = list.Where(x => x > Median)
```

`Find_Median(list1)` will return first Quartile, 
`Find_Median(list2)` will return third Quartile

Comment: What's 'X'? (The total numbers?)

Comment: That's the syntax for a Lambda expression. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: This is actually wrong in cases where you have multiple elements equal to the median.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into the same issue, and checking the [wikipedia entry for Quartile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile), it's a bit more complex than it first appears.

My approach was as follows: (which seems to work pretty well for all cases, N=1 on up)...

```
 /// <summary>
/// Return the quartile values of an ordered set of doubles
///   assume the sorting has already been done.
///   
/// This actually turns out to be a bit of a PITA, because there is no universal agreement 
///   on choosing the quartile values. In the case of odd values, some count the median value
///   in finding the 1st and 3rd quartile and some discard the median value. 
///   the two different methods result in two different answers.
///   The below method produces the arithmatic mean of the two methods, and insures the median
///   is given it's correct weight so that the median changes as smoothly as possible as 
///   more data ppints are added.
///    
/// This method uses the following logic:
/// 
/// ===If there are an even number of data points:
///    Use the median to divide the ordered data set into two halves. 
///    The lower quartile value is the median of the lower half of the data. 
///    The upper quartile value is the median of the upper half of the data.
///    
/// ===If there are (4n+1) data points:
///    The lower quartile is 25% of the nth data value plus 75% of the (n+1)th data value.
///    The upper quartile is 75% of the (3n+1)th data point plus 25% of the (3n+2)th data point.
///    
///===If there are (4n+3) data points:
///   The lower quartile is 75% of the (n+1)th data value plus 25% of the (n+2)th data value.
///   The upper quartile is 25% of the (3n+2)th data point plus 75% of the (3n+3)th data point.
/// 
/// </summary>
internal Tuple<double, double, double> Quartiles(double[] afVal)
{
    int iSize = afVal.Length;
    int iMid = iSize / 2; //this is the mid from a zero based index, eg mid of 7 = 3;

    double fQ1 = 0;
    double fQ2 = 0;
    double fQ3 = 0;

    if (iSize % 2 == 0)
    {
        //================ EVEN NUMBER OF POINTS: =====================
        //even between low and high point
        fQ2 = (afVal[iMid - 1] + afVal[iMid]) / 2;

        int iMidMid = iMid / 2;

        //easy split 
        if (iMid % 2 == 0)
        {
            fQ1 = (afVal[iMidMid - 1] + afVal[iMidMid]) / 2;
            fQ3 = (afVal[iMid + iMidMid - 1] + afVal[iMid + iMidMid]) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            fQ1 = afVal[iMidMid];
            fQ3 = afVal[iMidMid + iMid];
        }
    }
    else if (iSize == 1)
    {
        //================= special case, sorry ================
        fQ1 = afVal[0];
        fQ2 = afVal[0];
        fQ3 = afVal[0];
    }
    else
    {
        //odd number so the median is just the midpoint in the array.
        fQ2 = afVal[iMid];

        if ((iSize - 1) % 4 == 0)
        {
            //======================(4n-1) POINTS =========================
            int n = (iSize - 1) / 4;
            fQ1 = (afVal[n - 1] * .25) + (afVal[n] * .75);
            fQ3 = (afVal[3 * n] * .75) + (afVal[3 * n + 1] * .25);
        }
        else if ((iSize - 3) % 4 == 0)
        {
            //======================(4n-3) POINTS =========================
            int n = (iSize - 3) / 4;

            fQ1 = (afVal[n] * .75) + (afVal[n + 1] * .25);
            fQ3 = (afVal[3 * n + 1] * .25) + (afVal[3 * n + 2] * .75);
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<double, double, double>(fQ1, fQ2, fQ3);
}
```

**THERE ARE MANY WAYS TO CALCULATE QUARTILES:**

I did my best here to implement the version of Quartiles as described as type = 8 `Quartile(array, type=8)` in the R documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/quantile.  This method, is preferred by the authors of the R function, [described here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/sample-quantiles-20-years-later/), as it produces a smoother transition between values.  However, R defaults to method 7, which is the same function used by S and Excel.

If you are just Googling for answers and not thinking about what the output means, or what result you are trying to achieve, this might give you a surprise.

Comment: It works like a charm in my machine learning outlier finder. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question so I debated whether I should add below answer or not for a little while and since the most voted answer didn't match the numbers with Excel Quartile, I have decided to post below answer.

I also needed to find first and third quartile as I am trying to draw histogram and to create bin width and ranges I am using Freedman–Diaconis rule which requires to know First and Third quartile. I started with [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21009506/1718305).

But during data verification I noticed that result didn't match with the way Quartile is calculated in Excel and histogram created using [Ploltly](https://plot.ly/javascript/) so I dig further and stumbled upon following two links:

- [C# Descriptive Statistic Class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27340/A-User-Friendly-C-Descriptive-Statistic-Class)
- [Statistics](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0073373605/582608/Chap001.ppt) - check slide 12

Slide 12 in second link states "The position of the Pth percentile is given by `(n + 1)P/100`, where n is the number of observations in the set."

So equivalent C# code from [C# Descriptive Statistic Class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27340/A-User-Friendly-C-Descriptive-Statistic-Class) is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate percentile of a sorted data set
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortedData"></param>
    /// <param name="p"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static double Percentile(double[] sortedData, double p)
    {
        // algo derived from Aczel pg 15 bottom
        if (p >= 100.0d) return sortedData[sortedData.Length - 1];

        double position = (sortedData.Length + 1) * p / 100.0;
        double leftNumber = 0.0d, rightNumber = 0.0d;

        double n = p / 100.0d * (sortedData.Length - 1) + 1.0d;

        if (position >= 1)
        {
            leftNumber = sortedData[(int)Math.Floor(n) - 1];
            rightNumber = sortedData[(int)Math.Floor(n)];
        }
        else
        {
            leftNumber = sortedData[0]; // first data
            rightNumber = sortedData[1]; // first data
        }

        //if (leftNumber == rightNumber)
        if (Equals(leftNumber, rightNumber))
            return leftNumber;
        double part = n - Math.Floor(n);
        return leftNumber + part * (rightNumber - leftNumber);
    } // end of internal function percentile
```

Test case (written in Visual Studio 2017):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        double[] x = { 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 32, 33, 49, 52, 56 };
        var q1 = Percentile(x, 25);
        var q2 = Percentile(x, 50);
        var q3 = Percentile(x, 75);
        var iqr = q3 - q1;

        var (q1_mike, q2_mike, q3_mike) = Quartiles(x); //Uses named tuples instead of regular Tuple
        var iqr_mike = q3_mike - q1_mike;
    }
```

Result comparison:

You will notice that result in excel matches to the theory mentioned [Statistics](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0073373605/582608/Chap001.ppt) in slide 12.

- From code:

[image: Quartile value comparison]

- From excel (matches q1, q2 and q3 values)

[image: Same result in excel]

Comment: Thank You - great documentation with the excel comparative

Answer (score 0):

a quick way that can be adjusted

```
var q3 = table.Skip(table.Length * 3 / 4).Take(1);
var q1 = table.Skip(table.Length * 1 / 4).Take(1);
```